# Given a decreasing family of sets and partitions with a refinement condition, is there a monotonous choice function from the partitions?

Tags: set-theory, set-partition

I have been trying to show the statement below using the $AC$ but I am starting to think that it is not strong enough to do it.

**Context:** Let $\Gamma$ be an uncountable linearly ordered set with a smallest element (not necessarily well-ordered).

For each $\alpha\in\Gamma$, let $C_\alpha$ be a non-empty set such that $C_\alpha\supsetneqq C_\beta$ whenever $\alpha<\beta$.
For each $\alpha\in\Gamma$, let $P(C_\alpha)$ be a partition of $C_\alpha$ such that: whenever  $\alpha<\beta$, for all $B\in P(C_\beta)$, there exists $A\in P(C_\alpha)$ such that $B\subsetneqq A$.

> **Statement:** There exists $\{A_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in\Gamma}$ such that $A_\alpha\in P(C_\alpha)$ and $A_\alpha\supsetneqq A_\beta$ whenever
>   $\alpha<\beta$.

By using the AC we can see that there exists $\{A_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in\Gamma}$ such that $A_\alpha\in P(C_\alpha)$, but (I think) there is nothing to ensure the monotonicity condition: $A_\alpha\supsetneqq A_\beta$ whenever $\alpha<\beta$.

Maybe the statement is a well-known result or conjecture that I am not aware of, I would appreciate some answer or reference.

Comment: @Morgan: That's really the only way to understand that statement. From this set theorist's perspective, there is no confusion there. (Although I agree that the formulation is a bit odd and could be cleaner, as you suggest.)

Comment: I think it would simplify problem somewhat if you reversed the ordering on $\Gamma$, so that all of the inequalities go the same direction. i.e. $\alpha < \beta$ implies $C_\alpha \subset C_\beta$.

Comment: The axiom of choice is somewhat of a red herring in this discussion, I have to admit. Since the "default" is to assume choice, you should just be asking if that statement can be proved (sure, one can mention choice explicitly in the body of the question, but it's not the main topic). Also a better title is in order.

Comment: @Hurkyl: Actually the question has a natural solution when the sets are descending. But since it's 2am, I leave you with the daunting task of fixing my answer to match your proposed edit... because it doesn't fit anymore.

Comment: Do you want to also require that for any $A\in P(C_\alpha)$, there exists $B\in P(C_\beta)$ such that $B\subset A$?  Otherwise you can get some very easy counterexamples with $\Gamma=\mathbb{N}$.  (Also, do you mean for all of your inclusions to be strict?  That artificially makes counterexamples more annoying to construct without actually changing what's going on.)

Comment: Assuming that the sets $C_\alpha$ are in strictly descending order, it is only required that for any $B\in P(C_\beta)$ there exists $A\in P(C_\alpha)$ such that $B\subsetneqq A$ whenever $\alpha<\beta$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me first ignore your requirements that $\Gamma$ is uncountable and that the containments are strict, since these requirements are wholly artificial and have nothing to do with what's going on, and just make counterexamples a bit messier.  Here, then, is the prototypical counterexample.  Let $\Gamma=\mathbb{N}$, let $C_n=\{m\in\mathbb{N}:m\geq n\}$, and let $P(C_n)$ be the partition of $C_n$ into singleton sets.  There is then no sequence of the sort you ask for since each singleton set $\{k\}$ in any of the partitions stops existing once you reach $C_{k+1}$.

OK, now if you insist, we can bulk this example up to meet all your requirements.  Let's take $\Gamma=[0,\infty)\subset\mathbb{R}$, and let $C_x=\{(y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^2:y,z\geq x\}$, and let $P(C_x)$ be the partition into sets of the form $\{y\}\times[x,\infty)$.  Now $\Gamma$ is uncountable and all the inclusions are strict, but the sequence you ask for fails to exist for the same reason as in the first example.

Comment: Yeah, much simpler than my example! (And even more illuminating as to how the axiom of choice is irrelevant to the discussion...)

Comment: Your answer is based on the assumption that any element of $P(C_\alpha)$ has an element of $P(C_\beta)$ below it whenever $\alpha<\beta$, which makes the problem considerably more interesting.

Comment: You mean that the partitions are essential refinements (to the restrictions, that is), I guess. And yes, I agree that does make the example much more interesting.

Comment: @AsafKaragila . I have heard a few attempted pronunciations of "Aronszajn  tree" and  decided that it means "Are-n't Chain  tree"..... :)

Comment: @Daniel: I prefer the Shoeshine tree... :)

Answer (score 5):

The answer is negative. This is not provable, even when assuming the axiom of choice. Even under the assumption that $\Gamma$ is a well-ordered set.

Let $T$ be a tree of height $\omega_1$ without a branch (either an Aronszajn tree, assuming choice; or any counterexample to $\sf DC_{\omega_1}$ otherwise).

Let $C_\alpha$ be $T\setminus T\restriction\alpha$, namely all the nodes of height at least $\alpha$. The partition is easy, $P(C_\alpha)$ is simply the set of subtrees above each node in the $\alpha$th level of $T$.

Easily, the sets $C_\alpha$ are descending, and the partitions refine each other. But now, if $A_\alpha$ is as descending choice sequence, by the fact that each $A_\alpha$ has a unique root, this would give us a branch. But the assumption on $T$ is that it has no uncountable branches, which is a contradiction.